What is the algorithm for determining what energy is spent on in a quantum chemical reaction?
The law of conservation of energy tells us that the sum of the potential and kinetic energy of a system is constant.
Suppose two atoms/molecules collide (each has its own velocity vector) and an exothermic chemical reaction occurs between them. The chemical reaction released energy in the form of photons and temperature. As we know the energy of an atom/molecule in the ground state is quantized.
The question arises, where does the excess energy in this reaction go? It cannot be completely released in the form of photon (only portions of energy are placed in it). Accordingly it seems that the energy should be transferred to the velocity of molecules of the chemical reaction results.
There appears a question, how to determine in what way energy will be distributed on photons and velocities of particles of results of chemical reaction?
Will the number of emitted photons in chemical reaction be random or always the same?
Will the energy levels of these photons be random or predictable?
With what degree of confidence can the vectors (direction and amount of velocity) of the velocity of the molecules of the chemical reaction results be determined (given the Heisenberg uncertainty)?
What part of the energy will go to photons and what part will go to the velocity of chemical reaction results?

Your question is based on an incorrect assumption.

Suppose two atoms/molecules collide (each has its own velocity vector [sic]). As we know the energy of an atom/molecule [sic] is quantized.

Quantized energy exists in bound state$^1$ systems, and the interaction you describe (collision between free particles of arbitrary energy) is not a bound state system.
You may want to consider the distinction between absorption excitation (a photon needs to carry an energy that is exactly the difference between two electron energy levels)
and collisional excitation (a particle, e.g., an electron can collide with an atom so that the atom will absorb a fraction of the electron's initial kinetic energy, and some kinetic energy will be left over in the scattered electron).
Because of your original assumption, the rest of your question is moot.
$^1$ For example, electrons in atomic orbitals exist with fixed energies (and angular momentum).

Thanks for the reply. But still the model of energy exchange in a chemical reaction did not appear in my mind. However, I realized that because of the uncertainty principle we cannot tell what the velocities of the reactants are. Is there any chapter of the book that can be read to understand this?
